# Rails/RSpec - Simulating request from same browser/session/user (not signed in). To check if a cookie was set in a previous request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a referral system. So if a user (not signed up yet), visits a link, it will set a cookie.

application_controller.rb

```
before_action :set_referral

def set_referral
  if params[:referral_token].present?
    cookies.permanent[:referral_token] = params[:referral_token]
  end
end
```

Then the user can do whatever they want, and if they then later signup, I want to check for that referral token to give credit to the referring user.

1. Is this a good/the best way to achieve this?
2. How can I test this in RSpec? I basically just need to visit a route to set the token and then sign up.

referral_spec.rb

```
get "/some-route", params: {referral_token: "123abc"}, headers: something_here_maybe? 
post "/users", params: user_registration_params, headers: same_as_previous_user
```

Is there anyway in RSpec to ensure that both requests come from the same browser session? I don't have much experience with cookies/sessions/etc. so perhaps my entire understanding is wrong here. Is there a way to test this? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a good approach
2. To test this you can have specs like:

Check in `controller specs` if the cookie is being set properly:

```
it 'sets a cookie with referral code when it is present in params' do
  get root_path, { referral_code: 'myreferralcode' }

  expect(response.cookies['referral_code']).to eq('myreferralcode')
end
```

If you want to test the full path e.g. when cookie is set with referral code, and the user registers and you want to check if referral code is set on the model you should use [feature specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec) for that.